# FragmentStatePageAdapter Doesn't Pause Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

I'm using a FragmentStatePageAdapter (android.support.v4) and I have setOffscreenPageLimit set to 2, so it creates and stores Fragments 2 ahead and 2 behind of the currently displayed Fragment.

Problem:
When the off-screen Fragments are *created*, they are also immediately *started* and *resumed* even though they haven't been painted to the screen yet. (!)

When the current page is changed and the corresponding Fragment is swiped off screen, it isn't *paused* or *stopped*. (!)

I've tried logging the behavior of all the callbacks in FSPA and its super class - *setPrimaryItem* comes the closest to being usable but appears to be called for all sorts of reasons, not just when the fragment is displayed.

**How can you detect that one of your Fragments is no longer displayed, or returning to the display?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a listener.

```
        mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener(){

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                if(mPageSelectedListener!=null){
                    mPageSelectedListener.pageSelected(position);
                }
            }

        });
```

Where PageSelectedListener is defined by you like so

```
    public interface PageSelectedListener{
        public void pageSelected(int position);
    };

    public void setPageSelectedListener(PageSelectedListener l){
        mPageSelectedListener = l;
    }
```

And use it like this in your fragment

```
    if(getActivity() instanceof MyActivity
        ((MyActivity)getActivity()).setPageSelectedListener(new PageSelectedListener(){
            @Override
            public void pageSelected(int position) {
                if(position==MyAdapter.MY_PAGE){
                    // do something with currently viewed page...like resume it
                } else {
                    // do something with any other page..like pause it
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, that does seem to be the only way.  Note: the selected listener doesn't fire on the initial selection, only subsequent ones, so you still need to handle the first resume elsewhere...kind of annoying